# Cakephp js helper params return wrong format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I have the following ajax link created with cakephp:

```
    $this->Js->link('more', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'more', '?' => array('type'=>$type, 'order'=>$order)), 
array('id'=>'moreelements', 'update' => '#pre_sandbox', 'complete'=>"resize();", 'cache'=>false, 'escape' => false));
```

The problem is that I get the following URL:

```
domain.com/posts/more?type=0&amp;order=0
```

As you see the & separator for the params is not showing correctly.

How can i fix that?

Comment: What makes you think that is not correct?

Comment: Is not correct because the second parameter ('order' in this case) is not processed in the controller. Returned array: Array ( [type] => 0 [amp;order] => 0 )

Comment: It depends on where and how you use it.  The & rendered as &amp; is correct in an anchor link in the HTML page.

Comment: Then how can I make Cakephp get the correct parameters in $this->params['url'] with the real name and not with key ['amp;order']

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on what you're trying to do but try using `HtmlHelper::url()` instead.